# how to change the value of a XML tag using tcl

Tags: xml, tcl

I have a XML file as follows :-

```
<ii:variable name="SERVER_IP" type="string" value="10.39.1.105:5005" />
<ii:variable name="DEVICE_WAN" type="string" value="em1" />
<ii:variable name="DEVICE_LAN" type="string" value="eth1" />
<ii:variable name="NUT_WAN_MAC" type="macaddress" value="00:10:18:DE:66:43" />
<ii:variable name="NUT_LAN_MAC" type="macaddress" value="00:10:18:DE:66:45" />

<ii:variable name="NUT_WAN_ID" type="ipv6interfaceid" value="0210:18FF:FEDE:6643" />

<ii:variable name="NUT_LAN_ID" type="ipv6interfaceid" value="0210:18FF:FEDE:6645" />

<ii:variable name="NUT_LAN_GLOBAL_ID" type="ipv6interfaceid" value="0210:18FF:FEDE:6645" />

<ii:variable name="NUT_LAN_ULA_PREFIX" type="ipv6address" value="FD00::" />

<ii:variable name="CONFIG_DIR" type="string" value="/cygdrive/c/Intact/33843evg/" />

<ii:variable name="DAD_TIME" type="integer" value="240000" />
<ii:variable name="DHCP_SOL_WAIT" type="integer" value="10000" />
<ii:variable name="DHCP_LAN_SOL" type="integer" value="5000" />
```

Now, I want the change the "value" field for certain variable "name" fields , like ii:variable name="NUT_WAN_MAC, ii:variable name="NUT_LAN_MAC,etc etc . 
what is the best way to do that using TCL script.

Comment: To do this properly, you'd want http://tclxml.sourceforge.net/tclxml.html

Comment: Another alternative is http://tdom.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

The tdom package is good at this sort of thing:

```tcl
package require tdom

# Parse the XML into a DOM tree
set doc [dom parse $thexml]

# Note that we've got a (multi-line) list of the changes to make
# and that I have *NO* idea what you want to set things to!
foreach {name setTo} {
    NUT_WAN_MAC "the quick brown fox"
    NUT_LAN_MAC "the lazy dogs"
} {
    # using a loop in case there are several nodes with that name :-)
    foreach node [$doc selectNodes [format {//ii:variable[@name="%s"]} $name]] {
        $node setAttribute value $setTo
    }
}

# Convert back into XML; you might want to experiment with the -indent option
set thechangedxml [$doc asXML]
```

You might need to experiment with getting the right thing for the XPath to use in the `selectNodes` method to select the nodes you want to modify; these things are not always trivial. If you're working with XPath including `[`filters`]`, remember to brace the overall expression to prevent double-interpretation, and the `format` command can help you stay sane here.

And yes, you can make this a lot more complicated if you want. (I've omitted the code for reading and writing files. That's pretty standard.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Donal , i tried the code but it does not work . actually let me put the entire file that I am talking about. the filename is "devices.xml" and the contents are :-